# how to configure memory size for asp.net inproc cache

Tags: asp.net, iis, caching

I do not want asp.net to take decision on when the items in the cache should be invalidated, rather the business logic should trigger the cache clean up.

Asp.net automatically invalidates some items from the cache when the cache usage reaches a particular threshold value (inbuilt optimization in the framework).

As of now the virtual memory settings on IIS for the thread pool is set to default.
Is this somewhere I should make changes so that the threashold for the cache to expire will automatically bump up to a higher level.

We are around more than 500 objects in the cache and do not want the cache to lose this data. While adding the items in the cache we are using *NoAbsoluteExpiration* and *NoSlidingExpiration* already.

But still somewhere when adding items to cache above 450 objects, the item count in the cache suddendly drops down to 300.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.johnsadventures.com/archives/2006/02/why_does_my_aspnet_cache_keep_clearing_i/) might just help you.

```
<caching>
  <cache disableMemoryCollection = "true"
    disableExpiration = "false"
    privateBytesLimit = "0"
    percentagePhysicalMemoryUsedLimit = "90"
    privateBytesPollTime = "00:02:00"/>
</caching>
```